# Open Excel File from Command Line Unprotected View

Tags: excel, cmd

I frequently open large excel files (100 MB+) from a network location that I completely trust. However, the default trusted domains on the workstation that I use does not include files on the network drive. It is cumbersome to load each excel file twice (once to open it from explorer, then again to 'enable editing', i.e. remove protected view).

*Is there an argument/switch that can be provided to excel.exe from the command line that will force a file to be opened in **unprotected(editable)** view?* I would find this less cumbersome than waiting for a large file to load twice.

I typically use **Excel 2010 and 2013**.

**Note**: I already know how to disable protected view through the excel interface, this is not the solution I am looking for, as these settings reset to their defaults everytime I log off the workstation.

I am also prepared to accept the fact that this might not be possible to do except in the Excel GUI. But if anyone has a workable solution, that would be brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: If the network location is fixed one then you can add it to trusted locations in Excel. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, that does work, but the workstation is set-up so that the settings reset everytime I log off. I'm really hoping for a command-line solution that I could throw into a batch file and just reuse that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there an argument/switch that can be provided to excel.exe from the command line that will force a file to be opened in unprotected(editable) view?*

**No.**

The protected view comes as a result of the level in the security settings, thus it would be a major security problem, if it can be avoided.

---

As a possible workaround - copy the files to your computer, mark it as trusted and open them there.

Comment: I think that this is most likely correct. I did some more looking, found a list of command line switches for Excel. There is an option for opening as read-only, but that is the opposite of what I want. I'm marking this as the answer, unless someone finds a solution.

Comment: Would it be a security problem? If a malicious software gains access to your registry or your command line, your PC is already pwned.